# fps is too low when ffmpeg grab video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, live, webm

I use ffmpeg with the following options:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

All I want to do is to watch the web live video in my chrome browser. This is relevant part in my ffserver.conf file :

```
<Stream test.webm>              # Output stream URL definition
   Feed feed1.ffm              # Feed from which to receive video
   Format webm
   NoAudio
    #Audio settings
   #AudioCodec vorbis
   #AudioBitRate 64             # Audio bitrate

   # Video settings
   VideoCodec libvpx            
   VideoSize 720*576           # Video resolution 
   VideoFrameRate 25           # Video FPS
   AVOptionVideo flags +global_header  # Parameters passed to encoder
                                       # (same as ffmpeg command-line parameters)
   AVOptionVideo cpu-used 0
   AVOptionVideo qmin 10
   AVOptionVideo qmax 42
   AVOptionVideo quality good
   AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
   PreRoll 15
   StartSendOnKey
   VideoBitRate 400            # Video bitrate
</Stream>
```

When I open chrome to the following location:

```
http://localhost:8090/test.webm
```

I can successfully watch the live video, but due to a low fps, I just doesn't produce a fluent video. I found out that the fps is only around 6. Sometimes it goes up to around 10 or 15. When that is the case, the becomes video a bit more fluent.

I have set the fps to 25, so I wonder why it actually gets to the low fps reate.

Comment: You can test pure encoding speed (using your same encoding options settings) without the added complexity of `ffserver`: `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libvpx -s 720x576 -r 25 -cpu-used 0 -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -quality good -flags +global_header -b:v 400k -f null -`

Comment: Thanks very much.I have tested it and I got a 10 fps speed.

Comment: @zhangyp007 Did you find any solution to increase input file fps? -r and -vsync 2 parameters doesn't work for me!

Comment: i had the same problem. turns out the VP8/VP9 codec (libvpx) is very expensive to compute. I switched to flv and was able to achieve a much higher FPS (from 4 to 30!). if you need to better performance for libvpx, sorry, i don't know how to achieve it.